# Fetching selected checkboxes from jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstree, jstree-search

I have a jstree with check boxes.
When I select a node and click on button then I am geting the name of that node.
But now I would like to allow multiple selection so that I have assigned check box to jstree each elements.
No how can I get the c=value of selected nodes.
Also I want to allow search in that but I don't know how to do it.

I have enabled ssearch plugin.
Here is my code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <style>
            html { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:62.5%; }
            body { max-width:300px; min-width:100px;  padding:20px 10px; font-size:14px; font-size:1.4em; }
            h1 { font-size:1.8em; }
            .demo { overflow:auto; border:1px solid silver; min-height:100px; }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="frmt" class="demo"></div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jstree.min.js"></script>
        <button>>></button>

        <script>
            $('#html').jstree();
            $('#frmt').jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data':[{"id":"NODE 1","text":"node 1","children":[{"id","node 2","text":"node2"}]}]
                },
                "checkbox" : { 
            "whole_node" : false, 
            "keep_selected_style" : true, 
            "three_state" : true,
            "tie_selection" : false
          }, "search" : { 
            "fuzzy" : true
          },"plugins" : [ "checkbox", "search", "state", "wholerow", "types", "selectopens" ]
            });
            $('#frmt').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
                   console.log(data.selected);
            });
            $('button').on('click', function () {
                alert($('#frmt').jstree("get_selected"));
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by

alert($('#frmt').jstree("get_checked"));

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare a array and loop over the checkboxes to identify which ones are checked and store it.

```
 var checked_ids = []; 
    $("#frmt").jstree("get_checked",null,true).each 
        (function () { 
            checked_ids.push(this.id); 
 });
```